# Txt Output is not what I am expecting

Tags: python

Goal of the assignment is to make a heat flow map of a soil profile at different depths (0, 5, and 10), the following code has not caused an error but the output text is not what is desired.

```
import math

kappa = 0.10e-6 # m^2 - thermal diffusivity
C = 0.58e6 # J/m^3/K - heat capacity
delta_z = 0.01 # m - grid spacing
model_depth = 1 # m
delta_t = 60 # s - time step
grid_boundaries = [x * delta_z for x in range(0, int(model_depth/delta_z))]
Flux = [x * 0 for x in range(0, int(model_depth/delta_z))]
grid_centres = []
T = []
Tsfc = []
T5 = []
T10 = []

for i in range(0, len(grid_boundaries) - 1):
    grid_centres.append( (grid_boundaries[i] + grid_boundaries[i+1]) / 2)
    T.append(20)
for i in range(1, int(86400/delta_t) * 7):
    Flux[0] = 5 * math.sin(2*math.pi * i/(86400/delta_t))
    for j in range(1, len(grid_centres)):
        Flux[j] = -kappa * C * (T[j] - T[j-1]) / delta_z
    for j in range(0, len(grid_centres)):
        DeltaT = (Flux[j+1] - Flux[j] * delta_t / C / delta_z)
    Tsfc.append(T[0])
    T5.append(T[5])
    T10.append(T[10])
T[j] = T[j] - DeltaT

with open('model_output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(1, int(86400/delta_t) * 7):
        print("%f\t%f\t%f\t%f" % (i/86400 * delta_t,
                                    Tsfc[i-1], T5[i-1], T10[i-1]), file=f)
f.close
```

My output is supposed to be 4 columns, (Time, Tsfc, T5, and T10) however the second third and fourth columns all come out as 20.00000. Is there something I have missed? Or something I can add? Sorry I am very new to python and am following a lab outline so without an error I am unsure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: `x * 0` is always `0`, there's no point in doing the multiplication.

Comment: Is your indentation correct? `T[j] = T[j] - DeltaT` is not inside the `for j` loop.

Comment: T is 20 repeated 100 times, apart from Flux[0], all others are zero. There are many issues, you should check your equations first.  Then add a few print, use a debugger, reduce the number of points to debug your code.

Comment: I am sorry, I know there is a lot wrong. What should I be looking for in my equations? What does the debugger do? How can I reduce the number of points to debug?